# Running a java program via nailgun

Tags: java, jvm, nailgun

Can someone please explain how do I start a program called main.java using Nailgun. It's been a complete nightmare for me and I cannot find any sort of tutorial on the web which explains it clearly.

Do I need to include anything extra in my program to run them?

I'm trying to follow the instructions given on the Nailgun website where it says:

```
Launch the Nailgun server with "java com.martiansoftware.nailgun.NGServer"
```

But the output I get is:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.martiansoftware.nailgun.NGServer
```

Also, when I try to run my compiled java program, the output is:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at com.martiansoftware.nailgun.NGSession.run(NGSession.java:261)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the idea with nailgun is that you have to include the classpath when you launch the **server**, like this:

```
$ java -cp /usr/share/java/nailgun-0.9.0.jar:path/to/myapp.jar -server com.martiansoftware.nailgun.NGServer 127.0.0.1 &
NGServer started on 127.0.0.1, port 2113.
[1] 22443
$ ng-nailgun com.user4215685.main
```